# Unable to remove the extension from Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I am not able to remove the `Sumo Paint` extension from `Google Chrome`. Every time the browser starts, I see it there. How can I force the removal?

ps. My OS is `Ubuntu 14.04`.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you click on the "TrashCan" icon?

Comment: it is removed after the prompt confirmation but stays there when I restart Chrome. @DavidPostill

Comment: Have you tried deleting the extension from `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/`?

Comment: There are lots of folders with meaningless names. How can I identify the right one? @DavidPostill

Comment: Activate "developer mode", goto `chrome://extensions/ ` and you will see the extension ID (32 lowercase letters). That will be the same as the folder name.

Comment: did exactly what you said - did not work. It is still there after restarting the browser. @DavidPostill

Comment: Hmm. Weird. You deleted the folder? Did the folder come back again?

Comment: yes, exactly. First removed from Chrome, then deleted the folder. Both them are there after the restart. Annoying.. @DavidPostill

Comment: One last suggestion. Try closing chrome **before** deleting the folder.

Comment: Still same unfortunately. Really do not understand why it is still there. A software in this scale must be consistent I think. @DavidPostill

Comment: Try closing chrome. Delete the folder. Create a new folder (same name) with permissions so that nobody can read/write the folder. Start Chrome.

Comment: It is still there; only the difference is that its icon is disappeared - replaced with a generic extension icon. @DavidPostill

Comment: I give up, no more ideas (other than it's loading from somewhere else)  :/

Answer (score 2):

First remove the sumo paint extension from chrome,

then goto chrome://settings/syncSetup and Select "Choose What to Sync" and then unchecked "Extension" option

then goto https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync and "Reset Sync" button. It will clear all your data from server, after complete it will ask for login.

Once you logged in all your local chrome settings and data will again sync to the server.

Restart chrome and again goto chrome://settings/syncSetup and Select "Choose What to Sync" and then checked "Extension" option, your local chrome extension will sysnc to server except "Sumo Paint".

Comment: It finally fixed it for me when I ... 1. Removed extension 2. Went to https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync 3. Clicked "Reset Sync"

Comment: When you go to  https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync  make sure you are signed into the same account that Google Chrome Settings is signed into.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get rid of the Sumo Point extension. It had to do the synchronization settings in the google dashboard.

When you go here: https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync - it showed me "1" extension, which was Sumo Paint. I was able to remove it, and since then it has not come back.

Here you can also chose what should be synced among your devices:

chrome://settings/syncSetup

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I have lots of extension and I want them to be synced. It seems the links you shared are about with the synchronization. I need it to be continued. All I want to remove Sumo Paint extension from my extensions (and also from my cloud too)